# Return an object along with a 409 Conflict error in a Web API 2 POST call backed by Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

I have a C# Entity Framework **Web API 2 controller**.  Currently when an attempt is made via the **POST** method to create an object with the same text for the main text field, I return a **409 Conflict error** as an **StatusCode** result to indicate the addition is considered a duplicate.

What I'd like to do is return the server side object that triggered the duplicate error too.  So I need something akin to the **Ok()** method but a variant that returns a **409 Conflict** error as the HTTP status code *instead of an HTTP OK status code*.

Is there such a thing?  How can I do this?  If I can make this work the client doesn't have to do a subsequent **Get** call to the server to get the existing object after receiving a 409 Conflict error.

Here's the current POST method:

```
    public IHttpActionResult PostCanonical(Canonical canonical)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        // Check for duplicate Canonical text for the same app name.
        if (db.IsDuplicateCanonical(canonical.AppName, canonical.Text))
        {
            // It's a duplicate.  Return an HTTP 409 Conflict error to let the client know.
            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.Conflict);
        }

        db.CanonicalSentences.Add(canonical);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = canonical.ID }, canonical);
    }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

EDIT: This solution is for WebApi prior v5, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43335622/1062224) if you are using v5 or above.

You could return a `NegotiatedContentResult<T>` that lets you specify the status code and an object to be put into the http message body.

Change your code to something like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult PostCanonical(Canonical canonical)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    // Check for duplicate Canonical text for the same app name.
    if (db.IsDuplicateCanonical(canonical.AppName, canonical.Text))
    {
        // It's a duplicate.  Return an HTTP 409 Conflict error to let the client know.
        var original = db.CanonicalSentences.First(c => c.ID == canonical.ID);
        return new NegotiatedContentResult<T>(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, original, this);
    }

    db.CanonicalSentences.Add(canonical);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = canonical.ID }, canonical);
}
```

Or maybe wrap it an extension method like this:

```
public static class HttpActionResultExtensions {
    public static IHttpActionResult StatusCodeWithContent<T>(this ApiController @this, HttpStatusCode statusCode, T content) {
        return new NegotiatedContentResult<T>(statusCode, content, @this);
    }
}
```

And then use the extension like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult PostCanonical(Canonical canonical)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    // Check for duplicate Canonical text for the same app name.
    if (db.IsDuplicateCanonical(canonical.AppName, canonical.Text))
    {
        // It's a duplicate.  Return an HTTP 409 Conflict error to let the client know.
        var original = db.CanonicalSentences.First(c => c.ID == canonical.ID);
        return StatusCodeWithContent(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, original)
    }

    db.CanonicalSentences.Add(canonical);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = canonical.ID }, canonical);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  That's two useful solutions I didn't think of it.  Nice and simple too.

Comment: No problem buddy, glad I could help

Comment: This will work but is unnecessary in the current version of WebApi.  Just return `Content(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, original)` (a built in method) to get the same result. See answer by @Kieran.

Comment: @Adrian cool, what version was the `Content` method introduced is it in Core?

Comment: I haven't been able to work out when it was introduced at this time but it appears to have been in the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core nuget package package at least since version 5.0.0 (10/17/2013).   I haven't done much ASP.NET Core, but I believe the equivalent is [StatusCode(int, Object)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.statuscode?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_StatusCode_System_Int32_System_Object_)

Answer (score 36):

You should return Content:

```
return Content(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, original);
```

`Content` is method on the `ApiController` class which will create a `NegotiatedContentResult` with the provided `HttpStatusCode` and content. There is no need to create your own extension method on the ApiController class like in the accepted answer.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I need!

Answer (score 26):

Arrived here looking for help with ASP.NET Core HTTP 409 - this is related, just the newer approach to solving this same problem.

#### Conflict ActionResult

```
 return Conflict(new { message = $"An existing record with the id '{id}' was already found."});
```

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar issue with ASP.NET Core 1.0 RC2, however I encountered a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`, using optimistic concurrency I did not want to allow my user to update an object that was already updated.

I also wanted to return the updated object to the user making the call.   I'm able to create a new `CreatedAtAction` and set the `StatusCode` to `StatusCodes.Status409Conflict`

```
context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
try
{
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
{
    if (!UserExists(id))
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    else
    {
        //remove the user we just added, otherwise it will not goto 
        //the database to obtain the updated user
        context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Detached;
        var updatedUser = await context.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

        if (updatedUser == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        var returnAction  = CreatedAtAction("PutUser", new { id = user.Id }, updatedUser);
        returnAction.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status409Conflict;
        return returnAction;                    
    }
}
```