# How to get data from C# Webmethod via AJAX statuscode?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

I am developing a code to check whether a data already exist on the server or not. If there is a conflict, then the program must return status code 409. I can get the data returned by the webmethod via ajax.success. However, I cannot get the data via ajax.statusCode. It always returns error:

> TypeError: data is undefined

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43335622/9360197)  but I got an error

> Non-invocable member "Content" cannot be used like a method

How do I get my object via ajax.statusCode?

**C#:**

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static Case CreateNewCase(int id)
 {
     try
     {
        Case caseResponse = new Case();

        //some process about checking if the ID exists and loading other data

        if(idCount > 0)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 409;
            return caseResponse;
        }
        else
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 200; 
            return caseResponse;
        } 
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 500;
         return null;
     }
}
```

**JS:**

```
function newCase() {

$.ajax({
    url: 'Default.aspx/CreateNewCase',
    data: JSON.stringify(
        {id: ID }
    ),
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    statusCode: {
        409: function (data, response) {
             //how do I get the "data" from WebMethod here?
             loadCase(ID, data);
             //TypeError: data is undefined
        }
    },
    success: function (data, status) {
        loadCase(ID, data);
    },
    error: function (data) {
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you really need to use a WebMethod? Is creating a Web API or MVC controller an option? That would make things easier for you...

Comment: @RuiJarimba Yes. It is the requirement from the job. But to be honest I have no idea about Web API or MVC (I'm still new to C#).

Comment: Let's just say that `[WebMethod]` methods in `.aspx` or `asmx` files is the old way of doing this kind of things, and should be avoided (if possible). The best option for a REST API is [ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this. Use Web API instead of Web method and return   HttpResponseMessage  instead of case

```
public HttpResponseMessage CreateNewCase(int id)
{
 try
 {
    Case caseResponse = new Case();

    //some process about checking if the ID exists and loading other data

    if(idCount > 0)
    {
       return Request.CreateResponse( HttpStatusCode.Conflict, caseResponse );
    }
    else
    {
     return Request.CreateResponse( HttpStatusCode.OK, caseResponse );
    } 
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
    return Request.CreateResponse( HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, null);
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I got an error `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Page.Request'`

Comment: Sorry. did not realize that this is WebAPI. Now I got an error: `'HttpRequest' does not contain a definition for 'CreateResponse' and no extension method 'CreateResponse' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpRequest' could be found`

Comment: try to use System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage and  ApiController.Request

Comment: Your controller class should be inherit from ApiController

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the web method approach then change the ajax and try to parse the error in errro function as given below

```
function newCase() {

$.ajax({
   url: 'Default.aspx/CreateNewCase',
   data: JSON.stringify(
    {id: ID }
   ),
dataType: "json",
type: "POST",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",    
success: function (data, status) {
    loadCase(ID, data);
},
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, thrownError) {
   if(jqXHR.status =="409" ){
   var data= jqXHR.responseJSON;
    loadCase(ID, data);
   }
   else 
   {
   console.log(textStatus);
   }    
  }
  });
 }
```

Comment: Right now; I got an error data from 'var data= jqXHR.responseJSON;' is not defined. Maybe the http block the data because of status 409?

Comment: user JSON.stringify(jqXHR.responseText);