# How to pass additional context along with a Conflict() response

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, http-status-code-409

I have a Razor Pages page with some JavaScript sending form data to an API. The API tries to update the database, if there is a concurrency conflict, it returns 409. The JavaScript then checks if the response status is 409 and accordingly alerts the user with a message such as `Conflict detected`.
Q: How do I send back context along with the Response so that the user can see which data has triggered the Conflict?

### JavaScript:

```
var response = await fetch("api/dsr/updateStatus", {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(data)
                });

               if (response.status == 409) {
                    alert("Conflict detected.");
                }
```

### Controller code

```
IEnumerable<DSR> changedDsrs = // DetectIfConflict();

if (changedDsrs.Any())
{
    return Conflict();
}
```

I have tried changing the last line to `return Conflict(new { statusText = changedDsrs.First().ReleaseId.ToString()});` to no avail.
The posted code works fine: if there is indeed a conflict detected than the 409 is returned and the user is alerted - I just want to know how to add context to the alert text to display info from the `changedDsrs`

Comment: Have a look at this - might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43335622/660223

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Controller:**

You can return the following:

```
if (changedDsrs.Any())
            {
                return Conflict(new { message = $"An existing dsr was found." });
            }
```

**And in JavaScript:**

```
var response = await fetch("api/dsr/updateStatus", {....
```

`response` that `fetch` returned is a JavaScript promise. You can use `await` on it again to see the properties available.

For example

```
var text = await response.text();
```

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: no need to send an object inside Conflict, I can send a plain string e.g. `return Conflict("An existing dsr was found.")`. Thank you for your direction.

Comment: any idea why i cant seem to actually get the message text on the client via JS? its always just null or some BS status text "The page was not displayed because there was a conflict." I can never seem to find my custom text

Comment: @d0rf47 that was my problem - the answer is you need to write `var text = await response.text();`, i.e. you need to await the response

Comment: @Zvi i was actually awaiting it, what the issue ended up being in my particular case was a result of our IIS configurations. It was not properly configured for custom status responses so it was always just giving the standard 4xx error msg. I was able to change it though and now it works :)